# Excel Find Value next to max value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

If I do a simple formula such as

```
=MAX(J:J)
```

and I have a table such as

1 2
2 10
3 45
4 1
5 144

I would expect to see my cell = 144
is there a way for me to get the result 5 (as in the column to the left of the max?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want the value from column I try this formula

`=INDEX(I:I,MATCH(MAX(J:J),J:J,0))`

`MATCH` finds the relevant row number then `INDEX` gives you the value in column I from that same row